# How to get Wifip2pInfo object in wifi direct

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception, action, wifi-direct

It's giving a null pointer exception.I would like to get the IP address of a device connected via wifi direct.How to do this can anyone explain?Attached a [Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErM7T.png) to see.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have updated my answer regarding to your question. Please check it and let me know If it is working for you or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following code snippet, When WiFiP2pInfo has connection then it is not null but when there is no connection or connection lost then it will be null.

```
if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION
            .equals(action)) {

        if (manager == null) {
            return;
        }

        NetworkInfo networkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent
                .getParcelableExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);

        if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            manager.requestConnectionInfo(channel,
                    new ConnectionInfoListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onConnectionInfoAvailable(
                                WifiP2pInfo info) {
                            if (info != null) {
                                activity.setConnectionInfo(info); // When connection is established with other device, We can find that info from wifiP2pInfo here.
                            }
                        }
                    }

            );
        } else {
            activity.resetData(); // When connection lost then we can reset data w.r.t that connection.
        }
    }
```

Following code helps to find address of Client and Owner,

```
public static String getDestinationDeviceIpAddress(WifiP2pInfo wifiP2pInfo) {
    String destinationAddress;
    if (wifiP2pInfo.isGroupOwner) {
        destinationAddress = WifiDirectUtil.getIPFromMac();

    } else {
        destinationAddress = wifiP2pInfo.groupOwnerAddress.getHostAddress();
    }
    return destinationAddress;
}

    public static String getIPFromMac() {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    boolean isFirstLine = true;
    String ipAddress = null;
    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/net/arp"));
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (isFirstLine) {
                isFirstLine = false;
                continue;
            }

            String[] splitted = line.split(" +");
            Log.d(TAG, "** length **" + splitted.length);
            if (splitted.length >= 4) {

                String device = splitted[5];
                Log.d(TAG, device);
                if (device.contains("p2p")) {
                    ipAddress = splitted[0];
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return ipAddress;
}
```

And add permission **Read External storage** in manifest.xml.

Comment: Thanks for u r information Umang Kothari but what is "activity" there??Its showing some error there saying that symbol can't be resolved

Comment: Yes, activity is object of respected Activity from which you have registered this receiver and you want connection information on that Activity back.

Comment: It's giving a new error Kothari

"android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
            at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1128)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getHostByAddrImpl(InetAddress.java:438)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getHostName(InetAddress.java:307)
            at com.example.hp1.myproject3.MainActivity$Myreceiver$2.onConnectionInfoAvailable(MainActivity.java:231)
            at android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager$Channel$P2pHandler.handleMes

Comment: Because getting IP address is network operation and you have to do such operations in worker thread not on UI thread. Use asynctask mechanism for getting IP address

Comment: it's still showing null pointer exception on info object kothari.Anyway thank u so much for u r help

Comment: @srinivas Please read WiFiP2p document carefully. Because it works for me so it will work for you too. I have developed chat app with WiFiP2p and  It works with charm.

Comment: If you think that my answer is helpful then please mark it.

Comment: @Kothari can u please share me the link of that wifip2p document

Comment: @Kothari Finally i got the info object and got the group owner address but again i got stuck at client address??could u help mee here tooo..Thanks in advance

Comment: That's great! Please check answer again, I have added information for getting client address and owner address.

Comment: @Kothari it's showing null pointer exception in the else part as there would be no info object on client side:
so I tried this code for starting communication from clientSocket socket=new Socket();
socket.Connect(new InetAddress("192.168.69.1",8888));//as Group owner address is always 192.168.69.1 ,can we do sooo???but its showing "ECONNREFUSED" ERROR

Comment: Please call this method after connection is stable between two devices!